# FragmentStatePagerAdapter : continue to show the current fragment after dataset is changed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have a viewPager.

Say underlying dataset is d0,d1,d2,d3,etc, and corresponding fragments are f0,f1,f2,f3...

Currently Fragment f1 is visible i.e. position 1 of `ViewPager`. d0, is removed and `notifyDataSetChanged` is called on the adapter.

Now, the current visible fragment will become f2 i.e. f2 will be in position 1, while f1 will be in position 0, of `ViewPager`

I want that f1 to remain visible after the change in the dataset, i.e., `ViewPager` should show `Fragment` corresponding to position 0.

How to achieve this?

Edit : Currently, I am using `viewpager.setCurrentItem(int position)` to achieve this, but it has jerky UI experience. The changing of the `viewPager` items is visible to the user.

Comment: Please be more specific, or even better, post some relevant code

Comment: @AbrahamyanSamvel I have edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: have you achieved this? I am currently trying to do this

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `viewpager.setCurrentItem(int position)` with the position of the fragment you want.

Comment: Yes, I am using that currently, but it is jerky experience. The changing of `Fragment` is visible.

Comment: That's because you are calling notifyDataSetChanged() and make the viewpager redraw the tabs and fragments

Comment: Is there alternative to `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: Have you tried to extend FragmentStatePagerAdapter for ViewPager adapter ?